# Can I create rasters from points with values based on a related table?

Tags: file-geodatabase, raster-conversion

I have weed mapping (points) and weed monitoring (tabular related table) data in a file geodatabase.  I would like to convert the points to raster based on the weed cover values in the weed monitoring related table.  The points to raster conversion function doesn't allow me to select values from the related table.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Comment: First join the table, then copy the desired value(s) over to your points data, then convert to raster. (Alternatively, interpolate the points -- but the choice of direct vs. interpolate depends on your end goal!)